# Using el-input in el-dropdown does not allow to input a whitespace into the input field

Tags: typescript, components, vuejs3, element-plus

**Environment**

1. Vue Version: 3.3.4
2. Element Plus Version: 2.3.6
3. Browser / OS: Chrome/114.0.5735.134

[Reproduction at Element Plus Pleyground](https://element-plus.run/#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)

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Input some text into the field
2. Input a white space

**What is Expected?**
You can see a whitespace in the input field

**What is actually happening?**
No whitespace, hitting spacebar only triggers a dropdown menu and after multiple smashing input field loses it focus.

**Additional comment**
I am working on an input field which could promts users about existing names in the system. Recently I noticed this erroneous behavior and just don`t understand why smashing spacebar triggers a dropdown window except input field (adding whitespace in the field)

Unfortunately I did not succeed in investigating the problem and why spacetab triggers dropdown window.